# tidyeval functions and problems with `View()`

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyeval

Code chunk #1 and #2 are identical, except for line number 14. Code chunk #1 uses a `print()` call and code chunk #2 uses the `View()` call. Code chunk #1 works fine. Code chunk #2 gives the error `"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cal.date' not found"`. Why?

## 1

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
graph.data <- tibble(cal.date = as.Date(40100:40129, origin = "1899-12-30"), 
                     random_num = rnorm(30, 8, 5))

child_function <- function(df, variable, hor.line = 6) {  
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  df <- df %>% mutate(mutation = 2 * !!variable, horizontal.line = hor.line)
}

parent_function <- function(df, date, variable, hor.line = 6) {
  date <- enquo(date)
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  df <- df %>% child_function(!!variable, hor.line) %>% print()  # LINE 14
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(!!date, mutation)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = hor.line))
  p
}

parent_function(graph.data, date = cal.date, variable = random_num, hor.line = 8)
```

## 2

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
graph.data <- tibble(cal.date = as.Date(40100:40129, origin = "1899-12-30"), 
                     random_num = rnorm(30, 8, 5))

child_function <- function(df, variable, hor.line = 6) {  
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  df <- df %>% mutate(mutation = 2 * !!variable, horizontal.line = hor.line)
}

parent_function <- function(df, date, variable, hor.line = 6) {
  date <- enquo(date)
  variable <- enquo(variable)
  df <- df %>% child_function(!!variable, hor.line) %>% View() # LINE 14
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(!!date, mutation)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = hor.line))
  p
}

parent_function(graph.data, date = cal.date, variable = random_num, hor.line = 8)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`View()` is a side effect function and does not *return anything*.

Use `%T>%` from the `magrittr` package instead of `%>%` for your second case.

`View()` ends the pipe such that you will want to have a `T pipe` instead. I think you can see it more clearly like this

```
 df %>% child_function(!!variable, hor.line) %>% View() -> df
```

vs.

```
 df %>% child_function(!!variable, hor.line) %T>% View() -> df
```

Comment: I think this requires an explicit `library(magrittr)`

Comment: @CalumYou, You are right! I always forget that `tidyverse` does not load it

Comment: Yeah, it's a little annoying but magrittr has name collisions with other tidyverse functions (extract, set_names). I hope they rename one or the other at some point since having the T and assignment pipes is nice